# How to execute a click handler before the end of the ripple effect in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using `<FlatButtin>` (or any other control for that matter), the click handler (or the redirection) happens only once the visual "ripple" effect has finished.

This makes the UI I'm working on feel sluggish, because once the button effect starts, I have to fetch resources in the backend, and the user must wait again.

I understand the interest of giving feedback on user actions, but the ripple effect feedback actually *blocks* further processing in my app.

Is there a way to bypass the ripple delay and execute the click handler right away - without hiding the ripple effect?

Answer (score 0):

Use [react-tap-plugin](https://github.com/zilverline/react-tap-event-plugin) along with `onTouchTap` handlers

Comment: I already use the `react-tap-plugin` but as I use [react-router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router), my `<FlatButton>s` handle the click to `<Link>`, which doesn't handle `onTouchTap`... Besides, I doubt this is the solution. The problem I have is on desktop...

Comment: What do you mean 'handle click to `<Link>`? Aren't you supposed to use [`push`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#programmatic-navigation) in such case?

Comment: Not necessarily. Using `<Link>` allows me to create a hyperlink declaratively.